# Uninstalling a Windows program using ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7

I have a dual boot pc and i accidentally installed a program which has made my bootmgr of windows 7 corrupt. I have access to ubuntu though. Is there any way that i can uninstall that program from windows 7 using ubuntu ?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, once your boot manager is corrupt, there is no way to revert it without a backup. Windows Repair might help, but since this is not a generic problem it might not work. Even if you could uninstall the program via Ubuntu, which you can, manually, I don't think it will fix your bootmgr error.

You can take a look [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2622803) too. It may solve your issues.

Answer (score 0):

In short: **No**.

You cannot uninstall any Windows program from Ubuntu. However, you can delete the files related to that program, but if the program has already done damage, you won't be able to repair the damage just by deleting the program files.

If you've dual boot (Windows with Ubuntu) and boot manager is damaged means that you've to reinstall GRUB. To install GRUB, boot from an Ubuntu LiveUSB, open a terminal and run:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
sudo update-grub
```

`/dev/sda` is the name of the harddisk. To find the name of harddisk run `sudo fdisk -l`.

[image]

Here `/dev/sda` is the name of the harddisk.
Restart.

Comment: 1st paragraph is correct. 2nd is not (reinstalling GRUB will NOT fix bootmgr, which is a Windows file used after selecting Windows in the GRUB menu)

Comment: If he has a dual boot PC with GNU/Linux as an operating system, then it should be the GRUB which has broken.

Comment: Wrong. He has access to Ubuntu so his GRUB is not broken. The problem is located AFTER grub, in the Windows partition.

Comment: No it is not grub, it is windows boot manager which is corrupt.